# Converting String format to integer is possible..?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, textbox

i would like to know is it possible to convert the string to int format.

eg: i need to store the the textbox value in to the variable state of type int. 
so, is it possible to store it..?

**My input value is string "Chennai", 
 if i pass this using int.Parse(textbox1.text) it shows input string is not in correct formate.**

```
int state=textbox1.text;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Now we have a bit more information**

It sounds like you don't want to parse a *numeric* string at all, which is the obvious interpretation of your original question.

If you want to *map* a string to a number, you'll need some sort of predefined map, e.g.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> StateNameMap = new
    Dictionary<string, int>() {
    { "New Jersey", 1 },
    { "California", 2 },
    ...
};
```

Then you can use:

```
int state;
if (StateNameMap.TryGetValue(textbox1.Text, out state))
{
    // Success
}
else
{
    // Input was not a known state name. What do you want to do?
}
```

**Original answer**

You can certainly parse a string to an integer, using [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

```
// This will just throw an exception if the text is not a valid int
int state = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

Or:

```
int state;
if (int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out state))
{
    // Success! Use state
}
else
{
    // Invalid text - what do you want to do?
}
```

This is the common pattern for parsing in .NET, including `DateTime` and other numeric types.

You should also consider what culture you expect the number to be in - less of a problem for integers than for non-integer values, but still something to consider.

Comment: i had try this method already.. it didn't work..

Comment: @farokemoahmed: a) you should have said that in the question; b) you should tell us in what *way* it didn't work; c) you should tell us the value of `textbox1.Text`. I can assure you that `int.Parse` *does* work, if you give it the right input...

Comment: please check my post i had updated it.. i'm passing the string value in the textbox eg:state names like New Jercy

Comment: @farokemoahmed: How did you expect us to know that? And what number would you expect "New Jersey" to end up as? That's simply *not* a number?

Comment: i'm actually not passing numbers, i'm passing string into the textbox.. so i would like to know that is it possible to convert the string value and store in int variable.

Comment: @farokemoahmed: Do you understand that your question doesn't give *nearly* enough information? Everyone was expecting the string to be something like "25" which has an obvious mapping to an integer. There's no obvious mapping of the string "New Jersey" to an integer. See my updated answer but *please* learn from this experience and ask a better question next time. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @farokemoahmed: Why have you accepted the answer that doesn't actually do what you want?

Comment: yes.. but i need this method to be used for the same problem.. so i used it..

Comment: @farokemoahmed: I don't understand your comment. Not only does the accepted answer not meet the problem you were actually facing, but it's not even the best answer for the problem you're *not* facing (as it doesn't mention how to detect that the input isn't valid). How can you have "used" that answer when you've said that equivalent answers didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

**After your edit:**
It looks like you are looking for dictionary mapper as Jon Skeet showed on his post, or an enum(if your strings are on worded):

```
    enum MyEnum
    {
      Chennai = 1,
      ABCD = 2,
    }
```

And you want to convert your selected value into an integer:
use this:

[Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    MyEnum val;
    if (Enum.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out val))
    {
        int myIntVal = (int)val; // myIntVal = 1
    }
    else
    { 
        // error
    }
```

**Before your edit:**

Use :

[int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

```
int val = int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
```

Edit due to @huMpty duMpty's request:
If you are not sure about the textbox's input value, use int.TryParse:

[int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int val;
if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out val))
{
   // val is a number
}
else
{
   // val isn't a number
}
```

Comment: This will break if the textbox contains a string value!!

Comment: This will break also if the application crashes.

Comment: Anyway, I've edited the post.

Comment: i had try this method already.. it didn't work..

Comment: Then you are probably doing something wrong. Please post the whole code and we will help you.

Comment: @farokemoahmed - I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int state;

int.TryParse(textbox1.text, out state);
```

Comment: Except without ignoring the return value, one would hope. Also note that initializing `state` before calling `TryParse` is pointless.

Comment: But still ignoring the return value, I see...